# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr

i have installed the tasseract using

```
pip install pytesseract
```

whenever i tried to run this piece of code

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
im = Image.open('hasan1.jpg')
print (pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

I got these errors.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "ocr.py", line 34, in <module>
 text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename))
 File "/home/hasans/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 193, in image_to_string
 return run_and_get_output(image, 'txt', lang, config, nice)
 File "/home/hasans/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 140, in run_and_get_output
 run_tesseract(**kwargs)
 File "/home/hasans/.virtualenvs/cv/local/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py", line 111, in run_tesseract
 proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
 restore_signals, start_new_session)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1551, in _execute_child
 raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'tesseract'
```

Comment: There are many questions about this topic... what have you tried and didn't work... and explain why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe PyTesseract requires you to have the tesseract library installed on your system - PyTesseract is trying to run the command-line interface but it can't find it presumably because you have only installed the python bindings.

If you are on an Ubuntu/Debian-based system, you can try:

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

You can check the Tesseract installation docs for more info: https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html

Comment: Can you update the link please ?

Comment: @LucasBodin Sure, I updated it